# The noun form of plant

Tags: word-usage, nouns

******I challenge this clause: Policy for questions that are entirely answerable with a dictionary.**
*

***If this question is entirely answerable with a dictionary, why do the three answers given to this question differ???********

**Which of the following shows the difference?**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/plantation

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/plantation?q=plantation

**People should open their eyes well before closing a question. My question is NOT about meaning, it is about the difference. Which dictionary and where does it show the difference? Look forward to getting the link.**

What do we understand by the word 'plantation'? The act of planting trees or the place or a farm where trees are planted? Is plantation the noun form of the verb 'plant' or is 'planting' the noun form?

Which of the following is right if a campaign is driven, motivating the individuals in a city to plant saplings so that there are lots of trees in future in the city?

1. Plantation campaign
2. Tree-planting campaign

Note that saplings will be planted by the individuals wherever possible, not on a particular, large area.

Comment: "Planting" is a noun in "I helped with the planting of the crops". Note the article "the" and the _of_ preposition phrase, both tell us that "planting" is being used as a noun in that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/plantation) tells us that a **plantation** is an area of farmed trees or other crops.

The act of planting (apart from the obvious 'tree planting') is

> **arboriculture**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> The cultivation of trees and shrubs.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/arboriculture).

Comment: The OED makes it clear that *plantation* can refer to the act of planting - seeds or plants -sense 2a. (*2004   Statesman (India) (Nexis) 6 July   Mr Routray had drawn up plans for plantation of trees and creation of water bodies.*) as well as a cultivated bed of either plants or trees - senses 3a and 3b.  The word also has various other - some metaphorical senses.

Comment: The usual form is "... the planting of trees ..."